# The endpoint at 'http://Foo' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

This project working perfectly at my local pc but when I run at server I am getting this error.

> The endpoint at 'http://Foo' does not have a Binding with the None
>   MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is
>   only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BIServicesSoap" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://FooA"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BIServicesSoap"
        contract="FinansService.BIServicesSoap" name="BIServicesSoap" />
      <endpoint address="http://FooB"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BIServicesSoap"
        contract="FinansNet.BIServicesSoap" name="BIServicesSoap1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Note:** At server there is another WCF project runs and my project runs under a sub folder. could web configs mix?

Comment: Your project is a WCF client application right?

Comment: my project is web app which uses web services as client but other project is unrelated WCF server. so I suspect about mixing webconfigs? or not.

Comment: It certainly sounds like you're client app is picking up another config. Why is the project inside the WCF service solution? If it's unrelated you should create a new solution for it.

Comment: Server is not mine :/

Comment: IIS has webconfig inheritance so sub folders can have settings applied from upper levels.  If you can make it in a different folder that is not a sub of the other.  Otherwise there may be a setting to disable inheritance.

Comment: I am gonna copy project to windows applicationto solve this :) thanks all